# D2L / BrightSpace - Create user within a course and within a section and assign user a role

Tags: api, post, desire2learn, valence

So I am trying to Enroll a user in a section for a particular org unit (Course)

This all works fine and I can add them into the section etc using:

```
POST /d2l/api/lp/(version)/(orgUnitId)/sections/(sectionId)/enrollments/¶
```

But the issue is, I am only able to POST one attribute, user ID. I need to be able to post the RoleID as well so I can specify whether they are a student or staff, as it assigned them 'teacher'.

Is there a way to do this / a different approach?

Cheers,

Alex.

Comment: EDIT: I have Done a POST to /d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/ with the updated RoleID and that seemed to update the users role as well as keeping them in the section etc. does anyone know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Enrollments in Sections and Groups are effectively treated as special sub-components of a Course Offering; the APIs that let you enroll a user into a Section or Group therefore assume that you want to take the user/role enrolled in the parent course offering and "assign" them to this Group or that Section (with the same enrollment role).

You are correct that if you want to have them enrolled with a different role, you should instead use the general enrollments API (assuming you have permissions; your calling user context may well have permissions to assign a user to a group or a section, but not to enroll them generally).